# How to safely delete public_keys created as part of `near login` flow?

Tags: nearprotocol

i've been practicing with the `near-cli` as part of my personal project to automate some tasks, this requires running `near login` quite a few times in debugging. However, when i do `near login` it seems to create a new public key every time, as when I do `near keys <account>` from time to time I see this list grow. When I did `near keys delete <public_key>` to cleanup, it did give a warning about accidentally deleting the wrong public key, so I attempted dropping keys older than the last one entered, however running `near login` again gave an error that I had deleted the key that gave access thru the web login. (I kept the key value and did `near keys add <public_key>` to restore access.

My question is, how best do I keep track of which `public_keys` are safe to delete when experimenting with the CLI this way?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is: Make sure you always have one keypair left. Keys are stored in `~/.near-credentials`, with files containing both the private and public part of the key. Always keep one of these files, and make you don't remove the corresponding key from the account.